# Display the 5 newest Items of ObservableCollection in WPF ListView depending on Timestamp

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have a ObservableCollection bound to a ListView trough a CollectionViewSource. I want to display only the 5 newest entries.

I tried filter the Items but it looks like the filter affects only the last entered Item. And since this is the newest it is of course displayed. Somehow all Items had to filtered again after adding a new Item.

Can someone point me to a solution.

Here some Code:

```
Public Class myItem
    Dim TS as DateTime
End Class

Public myList as ObservableCollection(Of myItem)
```

XAML:

```
    <CollectionViewSource  Source="{Binding myList}" x:Key="cvs" Filter="MyCVS_Filter">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="TS" Direction="Descending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

Filter:

```
Private Sub MyCVS_Filter(sender As Object, e As FilterEventArgs)
    Dim item As myItem = TryCast(e.Item, myItem)
    Dim listcvs As CollectionViewSource = TryCast(sender, CollectionViewSource)
    Dim list_view As IEnumerable(Of myItem) = TryCast(Listcvs.Source, IEnumerable(Of myItem)).OrderBy(Function(x) x.TS)

    If (list_view.Count >= 4) AndAlso (list_view(4).TS >= item.TS) Then
            e.Accepted = False
        Else
            e.Accepted = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could enable live-filtering on the `CollectionViewSource`:

```
<CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding myList}" x:Key="cvs" Filter="MyCVS_Filter"
                              xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                              IsLiveFilteringRequested="True">
    <CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
        <s:String>TS</s:String>
    </CollectionViewSource.LiveFilteringProperties>
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="TS" Direction="Descending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

**Enabling Live Filtering in a CollectionViewSource:** https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/01/17/989-enabling-live-filtering-in-a-collectionviewsource/

The other option would be to call the `Refresh()` method of the CollectionViewSource whenever you want to re-apply the filter.

Comment: That does not work for me, looks like the Filter is only reapplied when the LiveFilteringProperties is changing. I found out a refresh on the CollectionViewSource does the filtering for each Item again... i think i can work with this

Comment: Yes, the filter is only re-evaluated when the TS property changes. The other option would be to call the Refresh() method. I edited my answer to clarify this.